# Using specific web service

Tags: web-services

I'm trying to use a web service hosted in a government server in mexico. i have followed many tutorials but can't get it to work and i think its more complex than i thought.

The service is this one:
https://www.ventanillaunica.gob.mx/ventanilla-ws-pedimentos/ConsultarPedimentoCompletoService?wsdl

What i do is add it as a web reference on visual studio and then it shows me many clases and a delegate but no methods to use.

Comment: The WSDL only has one operation called consultarPedimentoCompletoPeticion. Can you find this in the project? SOrry I dont use Visual Studio much anymore.

Comment: See "[How to Consume a Web Service](https://johnwsaunders3.wordpress.com/2009/05/17/how-to-consume-a-web-service/)"

Comment: You should be using "Add Service Reference" if at all possible. "Add Web Reference" is part of the legacy ASMX technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF or ASP.NET Web API should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Namphibian i can't find that method. No methods shown either i add it as a services reference or web reference.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @JohnSaunders if i add it with the option "Add Service Reference" again not showing methods, just classes and a delegate. May i be missing something with that delegate?